# In a bytes object, which is the fastest way to perform a bit shift across bytes?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825319/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-right-bit-rotation-circular-shift-on-a-byte-array) seems exactly about this, but it is for Java.

Even wrongly doing the shift on a per byte basis (`local`), it is still slower than shifting across bytes (`glob`) through a conversion to integer:

```
In [394]: def local(ts): 
    ...:     return [((ts[i] << 1) | ts[i] >> 31) ^ ks[i] for i in range(16)] 
    ...:                                                                                                                               

In [395]: def glob(bs): 
    ...:     n = int.from_bytes(bs, 'big') 
    ...:     return (((n & (2**127-1)) << 1) | (n >> 127)).to_bytes(16, 'big') 
    ...:                                                                                                                               

In [396]: %timeit local(a)                                                                                                              
2.34 µs ± 5.38 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [397]: %timeit glob(a)                                                                                                               
647 ns ± 0.493 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [398]: a                                                                                                                             
Out[398]: b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'

In [411]: %timeit [bin(x)[1:]+bin(x)[0:1] for x in a]                                                                                   
3.94 µs ± 11.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: See like you've found it — what's your question exactly?

Comment: Those types conversion (possibly inside a hot spot of an application) don't seem a canonical way to solve it.

Comment: Python integers are variable length and support shifting. Built-in `bytes` objects are variable length but don't support the operation. If shifting them manually is too slow, it _may_ be faster to convert them to an equivalent `int`. shift them, and then convert the result back into a `bytes` object. There is no "canonical" way to do it that I know of.